# EntityDataSource Components and Foreign keys

Tags: database, entity-framework, webforms, foreign-keys

I have a webform that has two EntityDatasource components that are each attached to its own EntitySet.  So my first EntityDataSource is connected to an Entity named 'CContactsNames' and the second EntityDataSource is connected to an Entity named 'CContactsAddress'. Now theses two Entities are related via the EDM, but when I insert into one table the CContactsName table foreign key column pointing to the CContactsAddress Primary Key will not update. So when you look into the SQL Server DB the ContactsName foreign key field is left blank which each insert into the database. Am I missing something?  Should both of my EntityDataSources be using the same context?

By the way, I am using EF 5, .NET 4.5, VS 2012

Here is some of my code:

```
</style>
  </head>

  <body>
      <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <div id = "divContainer">
        <div id = "divA">
        <asp:Formview ID="Formview1" runat="server" DataSourceID ="CCContactsADS" DefaultMode = "Insert" >
           <InsertItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblFName" CssClass ="label" runat="server" Text="First Name:"></asp:Label><asp:TextBox ID="txtbxFirstName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FirstName") %>' /><br><br>
                <asp:Label ID="lblMName" CssClass ="label" runat="server" Text="Middle Name:"></asp:Label><asp:TextBox ID="txtbxMiddleName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("MiddleName") %>' /><br><br>
                <asp:Label ID="lblLName" CssClass ="label" runat="server" Text="Last Name:"></asp:Label><asp:TextBox ID="txtbxLastName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("LastName") %>' />
                <asp:Button ID="btnPerson" runat="server" Text="Create Person" CommandName="Insert"/> 
               </InsertItemTemplate>
            </asp:Formview>   



        </div>

         <br>


          <br>
        <div id = "divB"> 

             <asp:Formview ID="Formview2" runat="server" DataSourceID ="CCContactsADS2" DefaultMode = "Insert" >
            <InsertItemTemplate>      
           <asp:Label ID="lblAddr" CssClass ="label" runat="server" Text="Address:"></asp:Label><asp:TextBox ID="txtbxAddr" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Address") %>' /><br><br>
           <asp:Label ID="lblCity" CssClass ="label" runat="server" Text="City:"></asp:Label><asp:TextBox ID="txtbxCity" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("City") %>' /><br><br>
           <asp:Label ID="lblState" CssClass ="label" runat="server" Text="State:"></asp:Label><asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="CContactsStates" DataTextField="State1" DataValueField="StateID" SelectedValue = <%# Bind("StateID") %>></asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:EntityDataSource ID="CContactsStates" runat="server" ConnectionString="name=ChrisContactsAlphaEntities" DefaultContainerName="ChrisContactsAlphaEntities" EnableFlattening="False" EntitySetName="States">
                </asp:EntityDataSource>
                <br><br>
          <asp:Label ID="lblZipCode" CssClass ="label" runat="server" Text="ZipCode:"></asp:Label><asp:TextBox ID="txtbxZipCode" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ZipCode") %>' /><br><br>
          <asp:Button ID="btnAddr" runat="server" Text="Create Address to Person" CommandName="Insert" /> 
       </div>
            </InsertItemTemplate>   
              </asp:FormView>



       </div>
       </div>


          <asp:EntityDataSource ID="CCContactsADS" runat="server" ConnectionString="name=ChrisContactsAlphaEntities" DefaultContainerName="ChrisContactsAlphaEntities" EnableFlattening="False" EntitySetName="CContactsName" EnableInsert="True" >
          </asp:EntityDataSource>

           <asp:EntityDataSource ID="CCContactsADS2" runat="server" ConnectionString="name=ChrisContactsAlphaEntities" DefaultContainerName="ChrisContactsAlphaEntities" EnableFlattening="False " EntitySetName="CContactsAddress" EnableInsert="True"  OnInserted="CCContactsADS2_Inserted">
            </asp:EntityDataSource>


      </form> 
  </body>
</html>
```

**Here are my attempts:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

namespace ChrisContactsAlpha
{
    public partial class ChrisContactsA : System.Web.UI.Page
     {


         ChrisContactsAlphaEntities context;

         protected void CCContactsADS_ContextCreating(object sender, EntityDataSourceContextCreatingEventArgs e)
         {

             e.Context = (context as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext;

         }

         protected void CCContactsADS_ContextDisposing(object sender, EntityDataSourceContextDisposingEventArgs e)
         {
             e.Cancel = true;

         }


         protected void CCContactsADS2_ContextCreating(object sender, EntityDataSourceContextCreatingEventArgs e)
         {

             e.Context = (context as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext;

         }

         protected void CCContactsADS2_ContextDisposing(object sender, EntityDataSourceContextDisposingEventArgs e)
         {
             e.Cancel = true;

         }



        //protected void CCContactsADS2_Inserted(object sender, EntityDataSourceChangedEventArgs e)
        //{
        //    CContactsName myName = new CContactsName();
        //    CContactsAddress myAddress = e.Entity as CContactsAddress; 

        //    using (e.Context)
        //    {

        //        myName.CContactsAddressID = myAddress.CContactsAddressID;

        //        context.CContactsNames.Add(myName);

        //        context.SaveChanges();
        //    }


        //}

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            context = new ChrisContactsAlphaEntities();
        }

        protected void CCContactsADS2_Inserted(object sender, EntityDataSourceChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            int newPrimaryKey = ((CContactsAddress)e.Entity).CContactsAddressID;

            using (var context2 = new e.Context())
            {

                var order = (from o in 
                             where o.CContactsNamesID == newPrimaryKey
                             select o).First();

                  order.CContactsAddressID = newPrimaryKey;

                  context.SaveChanges(); 

             }


        }


    }
}
```

Comment: You should probably simply set a foreign key value (i.e. `ContactsName`), not a `CContactsAddress` object. But this is hard to tell without seeing some code.

Comment: Hi Gert! Sorry about that. I've added some more code. Hope it helps. :)